# ruby on rails rollback database created problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I completely rolled back my migration from the beginning so I can add a few columns, now when I'm trying to create new user I get a

```
NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create

undefined method `image_changed?' for #<User:0x007fa99ea152f8>
```

I'm using devise and I have carrierwave. My application worked, and I had images before, but when I rolled back and deleted the images from the upload folder, I get this undefined method.

Does anyone know where this is coming from? I'm completely clueless,

Thanks

Comment: This usually happens happens if you forget to add a column in your model's db table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that inside your `user` model you may have carrierwave still mounted to your model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader  
  #mounts the uploader to the given column in this case which it is :image
end
```

The error `undefined method`image_changed?' for #` indicates that you must be missing some sort of column fro your model.

1) `rails g migration AddImageToUsers image:string`

2) Run `rake db:migrate`